# Search an ObservableCollection by its objects fields

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm developing a Windows Phone application with C#.

I have an ObservableCollection defined as follows:

```
public class StartingPersons
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<StartingPersons> GetPersons()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to search inside the ObservableCollection returned by StartingPerons.GetPersons(); by the field NAME.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: you could look at linq, i don't know linq my self but it should be able to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
IEnumerable<StartingPersons> matches = StartingPersons.GetPersons()
                                                .Where(p => p.Name == "...");
```

This isn't specific to `ObservableCollection<T>` though - basically you ought to look into LINQ and particularly LINQ to Objects.